# fire click event for dojox mobile button

Tags: javascript, dojo

Hi I'm trying to call a click event I've set up for dojox mobile button, but cant get the event to call my function as shown below:

```
<script>
        require([
         ...
          "dojox/mobile/Button"
        ],
          function (..) {
              parser.parse();
              return {
                  //this function never gets called
                  Login: function (e) {
                      alert("you clicked?")
                  }
              }

          });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TabBar" data-dojo-props='barType:"standardTab"'>
        <li data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/TabBarButton" data-dojo-props='selected:true' moveto="viewLogin">Login</li>
    </ul>
    <div id="viewLogin" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/View">
        Login
        <button data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:Login">Login</button>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This way works:

```
require([
         ...
          "dojox/mobile/Button"
        ],
          function (..) {
              parser.parse();
              on(registry.byId("Login"), "click", LoginTo);
              function LoginTo() {
                  alert("I've been clicked");  
              }

          });




<button id="Login" data-dojo-type="dojox/mobile/Button">Login</button>
```